# how to remove curly braces and get proper output in csv file

Tags: powershell

I m trying to get the list of `vm` from `nutanix` with `name, ipaddress,` 
The output I am recieving includes ipaddress with curly braces which gives output as `System.String[]`

I have taken all the values in a array by using a for loop, than have exported the values to csv

Script which i have written is as follows-

```
foreach ($vmachine in $vm){
   $obj = "" | Select "vmName", "ipAddresses", "description", "protectionDomainName", "powerState"
   $obj.vmName = $vmachine.vmName
   $obj.ipAddresses = $vmachine.ipAddresses
   $obj.description = $vmachine.description
   $obj.protectionDomainName = $vmachine.protectionDomainName
   $obj.powerState = $vmachine.powerState

   $outArrayVM += $obj
   $obj =$null
}
$outArrayVM | Export-Csv d:\z.csv
```

Expected output should be some ipaddress like `10.x.x.x`, but m getting `@{ipAddresses=System.String[]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `$vmachine.ipAddresses` is a string array object. You want a string representation of that with controlled formatting. There are many ways to accomplish this. Here is one that will join multiple IPs (if they exist) using a `;`. If there is only one IP, it will appear with no semi-colon:

```
$obj.ipAddresses = $vmachine.ipAddresses -join ";"
```

Here's an example of your scenario:

```
$ip = @("10.1.23.45")
$ip.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

$obj.name = "test"
$obj.ip = $ip
$obj

name ip
---- --
test {10.1.23.45}

$obj | convertto-csv

#TYPE Selected.System.String
"name","ip"
"test","System.Object[]"
```

Converting the `ip` property of `$obj` to string forces PowerShell to interpret the property as a string rather than a collection. Thus, the braces notation (`{}`) goes away.

```
$obj.ip = $ip -join ";"
$obj | convertto-csv

#TYPE Selected.System.String
"name","ip"
"test","10.1.23.45"
```

Here are some other alternatives to set the `ip` property value as a string:

```
$obj.ip = -join $ip # No join character here. Works best with only one IP.
$obj.ip = $ip[0] # Accesses first element of array $ip, which will be a string. Only works with one IP.
$obj.ip = [string]$ip # Uses string type accelerator to cast $ip as string. This will join multiple IPs with a space between each IP.
```

**Explanation:**

When a `ConvertTo-Csv` or `Export-Csv` is run, the input object property is converted using the `ToString()` method. If the reference type of that object property (`System.Array` in this case) does not have an override for the `ToString()` method, then that method will return the fully qualified type name of the property. In this instance, that FQTN is `System.Object[]`. This is predictable with a little digging.

Testing with `[Int32]`, you would expect the string conversion to provide a string representation of the integer data because it **does** have an override:

```
$int = 1
$int.gettype().fullname

System.Int32

($int | Get-Member).where{$_.Name -eq "ToString"}

   TypeName: System.Int32

Name     MemberType Definition
----     ---------- ----------
ToString Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string format), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provid...

$int.ToString()
1
$int.ToString().gettype().fullname
System.String
```

Testing with `[Array]`, you would **not** expect the string conversion to provide a string representation of the array data because it **does not** have an override:

```
$arr = [array]1
$arr.gettype().fullname
System.Object[]
([System.Object[]] | Get-Member -Static).where{$_.name -eq "ToString"}

$arr.toString()
System.Object[]
```

See [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) and [Object.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) for supplemental explanations and examples.